# Input file multiple use with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

hello I'm working on a project to store images in firebase and then get the url of each image and store it in a database (firebase) the problem that I can not store those urls in the same registry would like to know if I can create an array with the urls of the images that I upload from a multiple input file and save them in a single record in this way.

```
parques:{
  nombre: "xxxxx",
  imgs:[
         "urls"
       ]
}
```

Here I leave the code:

```
var files = document.getElementById('file');
    var fullDirectory= 'imgs';
    var btnDatos= $('#btn-datos');
    var btnImgs = $('#btn-imgs');

    //proceso imgs
    files.addEventListener('change', function(e){
         for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) {
            var imageFile = e.target.files[i];             
            Imagencollage(imageFile);
        }
    })

    //subir imagenes 
    function Imagencollage(imageFile){
        var links= [];
        btnImgs.click(function (){
            var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref(fullDirectory+"/"+imageFile.name);
            var task = storageRef.put(imageFile);
            var name = imageFile.name;
            task.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){           
              //??
            }, function(error) {
              alert('no se subio el archivo');
            }, function() {   
              task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(downloadURL) {
                    links.push(downloadURL);                    

                    direccionImg(name, links);


              });
            }); 
        })
    }

    //subir datos
    function direccionImg(name, links){
        btnDatos.click(function(){
            var db= firebase.database().ref('parques/');
            var parque= $('#datos').val();  
            var data= {
                    nombre: parque,
                    imgs: links                                     

                 }
            db.push().set(data)
        })
    }
```

In front of you, thank you for the help

Comment: Hi there, please post your question in English so we can help. :-)

Comment: ok thanks for replying I changed the language...